# Uncaught Error: Expected an order id to be passed. PAYPAL

Tags: python, flask, button, paypal

I'm new to PayPal integration. And I'm trying to integrate PayPal smart button into my website running locally. I am using PYTHON Flask as back-end.

But I'm getting error `Uncaught Error: Expected an order id to be passed`
I'm not doing this first time. Before that I was able to successfully integrate button and have done real transactions. But paypal example scrip has changed.

I have copied this code from https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <script>
paypal.Buttons({
  // Order is created on the server and the order id is returned
  createOrder() {
    return fetch("/create-paypal-order", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      // use the "body" param to optionally pass additional order information
      // like product skus and quantities
      body: JSON.stringify({
        cart: [
          {
            sku: "YOUR_PRODUCT_STOCK_KEEPING_UNIT",
            quantity: 10,
          },
        ],
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((order) => order.id);
  },
  // Finalize the transaction on the server after payer approval
  onApprove(data) {
    return fetch("/capture-paypal-order", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        orderID: data.orderID
      })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((orderData) => {
        // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
        console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
        const transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
        alert(`Transaction ${transaction.status}: ${transaction.id}\n\nSee console for all available details`);
        // When ready to go live, remove the alert and show a success message within this page. For example:
        // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
        // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
        // Or go to another URL:  window.location.href = 'thank_you.html';
      });
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
```

And on backend I have this:

```
from flask import json
@app.route("/create-paypal-order", methods=["POST"])
def create_paypal_order():
    PRICE = 200
    products = request.get_json()
    quantity = products["cart"][0]["quantity"]
    value = PRICE * quantity
    paypal_json = {"intent": "CAPTURE", "purchase_units":[{"amount": {"currency_code": "USD", "value": value}}]}
    return json.jsonify(paypal_json)
```

Can anyone please help me? What I am doing wrong?

I was expecting a login form of paypal to show up.